# Methods from super class

Tags: java, loops, methods, superclass, println

I am writing a program to create an animal and need some help to create a method that when the health, energy, or hunger drops below a level of 20 the program will print out the noise of that animal. There is a super class of animal and i am currently working on a dog.

Here is an example of the code from the animal class:

```
public void setHungry(int Hungry) {
    this.Hungry = Hungry;
```

How to a write a method so that if the hunger drops below 20 the program will:

```
if (Hungry <= 20) 
System.out.println ("Grunt");
```

I don't have alot of coding experience.
thanks in advance

I forgot to mention this is a group task and i cannot alter the Animal class

Comment: If you need to check if the hunger drops below `20`, why you are comparing `hungry <= 0`? Also, try to follow Java naming conventions. Use names like `someVar` for variables/methods and use names like `SomeClass` for classes.

Comment: besides the fact that your code checks vs. 0 and not vs. 20, I don't see the issue. What exactly are you lacking?

Comment: Where do you alter this hungry value? I suggest you to write a control whenever you edit that value in order to check if it has became <= 20.

Answer (score 1):

Animal.java

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private int hungry;

    public void setHungry(int hungry) {
        this.hungry = hungry;
        if(this.hungry <= 20) {
            this.shout();
        }
    }

    public abstract void shout();

}
```

Lion.java

```
public class Lion extends Animal {

    @Override
    public abstract void shout() {
        System.out.println("GRRRRR");
    }

}
```

EDIT : considering Animal can not be touch you should change the definition of setHungry in your subclass. I assume you have a getter for the value ? Or the value is protected ?

```
public class Lion extends Animal {

    @Override
    public void setHungry(int hungry) {
        super.setHungry(hungry);
        if(this.getHungry() <= 20) {
            System.out.println("GRRRRR");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a group task and i cannot alter the Animal class

Comment: OK ! So can you give the code or at least the behaviour of Animal.

Comment: The code for the hunger in the animal class is: 
public void setHungry(int Hungry) {
  this.Hungry = Hungry;
 }    the methods for health and energy have the same layout

Comment: the hunger starts at 100

Comment: you don't give enough details for us to help you. please try a bit with the elemnts we gave you and open a new thread for assistance when you'll be a bit further

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' approach is valid but let me suggest another solution in case of you need this check somewhere else.

```
public abstract class Animal {

    int hunger;
    int energy;
    int health;

    public void makeNoise() {
        if (hunger < 20 || energy < 20 || health < 20) {
            System.out.println(getVoice());
        }
    }

    abstract protected String getVoice();
}


public class Lion extends Animal {
    String voice = "Grr";

    @Override
    protected String getVoice() {
        return voice;
    }
}
```